# How to remove rows from a struct based on a condition?

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct

I want to delete rows from a struct using a condition which is if `hsvmean` field = 0 then delete the row. I tried this code:

```
for j =1:length(selectedIms) % the length of selectedIms is 100
    if selectedIms(j).hsvmean == 0
        selectedIms(j)=[];
    end
end
```

But I get this error:

> Index exceeds the number of array elements (73).
>
> Error in HSVColorSelection (line 57)
> if selectedIms(j).hsvmean == 0

How can I delete these items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a solution in case someone needs it. Create a new struct in which there would only be the filtered rows

```
newSelectedlms = meanValues([meanValues.selected_ims]~= 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re deleting elements, making the array smaller, as you loop over the elements. The end index you loop over is determined at the start of the loop, hence you will index past the end of the array. You are also skipping over elements.

One simple solution is to loop starting at the back:

```
for j=length(selectedIms):-1:1
   ...
end
```

The other solution is to delete all elements at once. You could build a list of indices to delete in the loop, then delete those elements after the loop. Or do it without a loop:

```
selectedIms([selectedIms.hsvmean] == 0) = [];
```

Comment: Hey @Cris, just saw your answer, thank you, i tested all of the three solution they all work fine and i kept your last suggestion. one question thought (general one), is it better to avoid loops in code ? i mean if there is another option to do it without a loop (regardless of the data or type or it's size)

Comment: @Nissrine: The most important quality of code is readability (means you know what it does by looking at it, and makes it easier to maintain the code later). So if a loop is better readable, use that, until you determine it is slowing down your program. If your program runs too slow, use the profiler to figure out which bits take most time, then try to improve those bits. Often removing loops in favor of "vectorized" code is beneficial, but not always. It depends on how many function calls there are (these have overhead) and how much intermediate memory is needed for the loop-free version.

Comment: okay, it makes sense. i'm still learing things around matlab and coding in general, i've been told (and also noticed it) that loops slow down programs, that's why i'm asking and trying to get advices and tips :D . Thank you for the advice and clarification :)